# How to deploy a Java EE application in Intellij Idea

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, ejb, glassfish-4

Do you know how to deploy correctly a java EE application in IntelliJ IDEA? I don't like using NetBeans on Mac Os X. It has poor performance on my system. I have got some issues in running and deploying correctly an application on  that.

For instance I have these simple classes.

Could you explain me how to configure step-by-step the aforementioned IDE in order to execute correctly the client application? I already have Glassfish in my machine.

EDIT

well go step-by-step.
When I open IntelliJ IDEA, this is what I see:

[image]

As you may see, I have installed properly GlassFish. I choose EJB (since I use it in my application) and CDI. is it right?

---

```
package myejb;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface Hello
{
    public String sayHello(String name);
}
```

---

```
package myejb;

import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;


@Stateless(name = "HelloEJB")
@Remote({Hello.class})
public class HelloBean implements Hello
{
    public HelloBean()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public String sayHello(String name)
    {
        return "Hello, " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

---

and the Client application

```
package myejbclient;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import myejb.Hello;

public class HelloClient
{
    @EJB(lookup = "HelloEJB")
    private static Hello hello;

    public HelloClient()
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HelloClient client = new HelloClient();
        client.doConversation();
    }

    public void doConversation()
    {
        System.out.println(hello.sayHello("World"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have Community or Ultimate version of IntelliJ Idea?

Comment: yes I know that in java ee environment, servlet is typically used to run but it is just an example nothing more to show that everything is configured properly. I should be able to run client application and see in terminal Hello World when glassfish server is running but I got a java NullPointerException. I'm pretty sure that the entire application is not deployed correctly. Please help me to fix it...

Comment: What I don't understand is why no one could help me...it is two days I'm asking and no one is able to fix this problem. I ask you a simple question. If you had this code, how would you execute it on Intellij Idea ?

Comment: I have read the following guide http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_and_running_a_Java_EE_Hello_World_application. Now I have understood more thing than before. I followed it closely considering my web application no the servlet but the helloClient application. I have exploded the artfact and still not work. WHYYYYYYY?

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings and choose Application Servers. Add Glassfish server configuration there. Make sure you have **Glassfish Integration** plugin installed.

Then go to Run -> Edit Configurations... and add run configuration for Glassfish Server.